# Asp.net, dynamic loading of server controls from a DLL

Tags: asp.net, dll, custom-server-controls

I've been using reflection and LoadControl() to try and load a control dynamically from a DLL. I've had a problem, though, loading it from elsewhere than the app's ~/bin folder.

Is there any kind of restriction as to where you should be able to load controls from, and if yes, is there any way I can lift or bypass that restriction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206138/how-do-i-reference-assemblies-outside-the-bin-folder-in-an-asp-net-application). You can only load assemblies from the bin directory, the GAC or a codebase location.

Comment: It seems to suggest I can add a probing path from which I can load the control, but I can't get it to work. LoadControl doesn't seem to like that my reference is out of "bin"